# Nested Dictionary System.NullReferenceException in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, nested, vsto, public

I have scoured the internet looking for a solution to this problem but the null exception remains. Basically I am getting System.NullReferenceException error when attempting to add values to a nested dictionary.

Here is my code.

```
Public Dict1 as New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String))() 'Tried with and without()

Sub CreateDict(Length As Integer)

    Dim key As Integer
    Dim CmdName As String
    Dim CmdValue As String

    key = 0
    CmdName = "UnusedCmd"
    CmdValue = "NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,Read"

    While key <= Length
        Dim CmdDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        CmdDict.Add("Name", CmdName) 'Method 1 of Adding
        CmdDict.Add("Command", CmdValue) 'Method 1 of Adding
        'CmdDict("Name") = CmdName 'Method 2 of Adding Both seem to work as evidenced by msgbox
        'CmdDict("Command") = CmdValue 'Method 2 of Adding Both seem to work as evidenced by msgbox
        MsgBox(CmdDict("Name")) ' Returns UnusedCmd
        MsgBox(CmdDict("Command"))' Returns NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,NotAFolder,Read
        MsgBox(key) 'Returns 1
        Dict1.Add(key, CmdDict)
        key = key + 1
        CmdDict = Nothing 'Error Occurs whether or not this is commented out
    End While

End Sub
```

Note this code was adapted from my original project which was in VBA for outlook 2016. I am trying to readapt this code to be an outlook addin.

I have tried replacing the "As" terms with "=" and I have also tried

```
 Dim CmdDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

For both dictionaries but this didn't work. I have tried everything that I can think of / find please help.

Could it have something to do with it being a public dictionary? I saw someone else using a public dicitonary and they're solution was to add new which I new I had to do otherwise no object would be created.

EDIT:

I just tried a regular dictionary as a public variable and it failed as well. So it appears to have nothing to do with being Nested. I will continue looking into the public object issue.

EDIT 2:

Just Tried adding Dict1 to Public Class Still not working.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared Dict1 As Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String)) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String))
End Class
```

After doing this Dict1 was updated to GlobalVariables.Dict1

EDIT 3:

This code is within a VSTO Addin that I am creating based on macros that I wrote in Outlook VBA. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015. [The location of the code is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5TOK.png)

Edit 4:
Duplicate? I agree I thought that this was a duplicate answer as well but I couldn't anywhere else where the answer was to move the Create Object from Public to within a Sub for a public variable. But the rest of the question is very similar to others agreed.

Comment: That code runs just fine... where exactly are you getting the exception.... what line... what does the stack trace say?

Comment: The line that the error throws is at Dict1.Add(key, CmdDict) Not sure if it changes things but this is being run inside a Outlook Addin created inside VSTO

Comment: That implies the very first line is not being executed... WHere do you have this code located?

Comment: All of the code is located within a VB file within my VSTO project. Within the VB file the code is in a public module. Option explicit is on. As far as level that the VB file is located at it is directly under my project CustomFiling/VBFILE.VB . When I added the global Class I did so under CustomFiling/Outlook/ThisAddin.VB

Comment: ARe you sure that file is really a module... .

Comment: Your below code option worked. Thanks for your help. i am still not sure why it wasn't creating the object at the public level. and yes I ma sure it is within a module. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
Public Dict1 as Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String))
Sub CreateDict(Length As Integer)
    Dict1 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of String, String)) 
    <Rest of your code> 
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to give you a +1 because this answered my problem but I just joined and I don't have enough rep yet. Thanks Again.

Comment: JUst click the checkmark beneath it..if u see it

Comment: I'm still concerned the scope of that DIct1 may be off somehow though. Be interesting to see if it looks initialized from where you reference it.

Comment: I am curious about that too. I was planning to look into this just haven't quite gotten there as I have more errors in my code now that this functions.

Comment: I just called it from a sub separate from where it was created and the value was there so I think I am all set.

Comment: Cool... that's a better way to initialize anyway... If you ever need to recreate the dictionary again later.. it's all set to do-over.